# Error in msgget: no such file or directory

Tags: c, linux, message-queue

I know a similar question like this has been asked, but I also believe my issue is slightly different. I'm learning about message queues for a class assignment and the professor suggested we use this tutorial: http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/html/multi/mq.html . It's incredibly helpful and has a sample sender and receiver code titled kirk and spock.

kirk.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>

struct my_msgbuf {
long mtype;
char mtext[200];
};

int main(void)
{
    struct my_msgbuf buf;
    int msqid;
    key_t key;

    if ((key = ftok("kirk.c", 'B')) == -1) {
        perror("ftok");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((msqid = msgget(key, 0644 | IPC_CREAT)) == -1) {
    perror("msgget");
    exit(1);
}

printf("Enter lines of text, ^D to quit:\n");

buf.mtype = 1; /* we don't really care in this case */

while(fgets(buf.mtext, sizeof buf.mtext, stdin) != NULL) {
    int len = strlen(buf.mtext);

    /* ditch newline at end, if it exists */
    if (buf.mtext[len-1] == '\n') buf.mtext[len-1] = '\0';

    if (msgsnd(msqid, &buf, len+1, 0) == -1) /* +1 for '\0' */
        perror("msgsnd");
}

if (msgctl(msqid, IPC_RMID, NULL) == -1) {
    perror("msgctl");
    exit(1);
}

return 0;}
```

spock.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>

struct my_msgbuf {
long mtype;
char mtext[200];
};

int main(void)
{
    struct my_msgbuf buf;
    int msqid;
    key_t key;

if ((key = ftok("kirk.c", 'B')) == -1) {  /* same key as kirk.c */
    perror("ftok");
    exit(1);
}

if ((msqid = msgget(key, 0644)) == -1) { /* connect to the queue */
    perror("msgget");
    exit(1);
}

printf("spock: ready to receive messages, captain.\n");

for(;;) { /* Spock never quits! */
    if (msgrcv(msqid, &buf, sizeof buf.mtext, 0, 0) == -1) {
        perror("msgrcv");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("spock: \"%s\"\n", buf.mtext);
}

return 0;
}
```

When I initially compiled this code I ran across the error: **msgget: no such file or directory** when executing spock.c. I understand this error is typically because of a permissions/file path issue. However, the working directory of both files is the same, as well as the permission is properly set for both. I later found the error is removed when I type ctrl+c (^c) into the terminal once I've completed my input. My issue is this project is based on using a file input of text and while it is simple to have this code take in a file, I need to place a getchar() in order to request for the user to type the ^C interrupt in order for the receiver to properly read the message queue. I was wondering if anyone has come across this issue, and if so any suggestions for fixing it so that I don't need the user to request the ^C interrupt? Apologies for not posting my altered code however, understandably, my professor does not want any possible copying/plagiarism from other students.

Here is more detail of what I am writing in to the terminal:
Successful Output with use of ^C:

```
user@user-ThinkPad-S1-Yoga:~/Documents/message_queue$ gcc -o kirk -g -Wall 
kirk.c
user@user-ThinkPad-S1-Yoga:~/Documents/message_queue$ gcc -o spock -g -Wall 
spock.c
user@user-ThinkPad-S1-Yoga:~/Documents/message_queue$ ./kirk
Enter lines of text, ^D to quit:
value1
value2
value3
^C
user@user-ThinkPad-S1-Yoga:~/Documents/message_queue$ ./spock
spock: ready to receive messages, captain.
spock: "value1"
spock: "value2"
spock: "value3"
^C
user@user-ThinkPad-S1-Yoga:~/Documents/message_queue$
```

Output with use of print instructions, meaning using ^D:

```
user@user-ThinkPad-S1-Yoga:~/Documents/message_queue$ gcc -o kirk -g -Wall 
kirk.c
user@user-ThinkPad-S1-Yoga:~/Documents/message_queue$ gcc -o spock -g -Wall 
spock.c
user@user-ThinkPad-S1-Yoga:~/Documents/message_queue$ ./kirk
Enter lines of text, ^D to quit:
value1
value2
value3
user@user-ThinkPad-S1-Yoga:~/Documents/message_queue$ ./spock
msgget: No such file or directory
user@user-ThinkPad-S1-Yoga:~/Documents/message_queue$
```

Now, even though a proper output occurs when ^C interrupt is typed by the user, I don't want to have to type that into the terminal and simply want the sender program to be executed, then followed by the receiver program execution  with no need for a "quitting" action because a file will be loaded as the input for the sender program in place of the stdin.

Comment: Which of your two programs gave you this error ? I would guess it's the `spock` program. It requires that `kirk` is running before you run `spock`, since `kirk` creates the message queue.  You probably ran `spock` before you ran `kirk`.  Other than that, it's quite hard to guess what you are doing, so just copy paste everything you type in your terminal,  so we can see what you are doing - and explain clearly what you want to happen instead of what actually happening with clear reference to the commands and input you give.

Comment: Yes it is the spock program that is returning this error, and also I have been executing kirk before I execute spock as I understand kirk needs to write the input values on to the message queue in order for kirk to receive them. Thank you for the suggestion to add more detail I will do that now!

Comment: I have added more detail, I hope this possibly helps.

Comment: It looks like you quit `kirk` before you start `spock` ? You should run `kirk` in a one terminal, and leave it running while you run `spock` in another terminal - as that is how your code is designed to be run. As you see in your code `kirk` removes the message queue when it exits cleanly (If you input ^D), so `spock` cannot find the queue if you quit the `kirk` program. (While if you forcibly terminate `kirk` with ^C , it will terminate immediately, and not run the code that removes the message queue)

Comment: That's exactly it! Wow that makes a lot more sense too in terms of the whole point of message queues to begin with. Thanks so much, and now you've made me realize I don't know as much about message queues as I thought, time to do some more reading! :-) Thanks again!